# Force fancybox content "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

basically I am trying to launch a fancybox window when a specific button is clicked, and then I want to pass fancybox content to display, now my understanding is that if I do something like this it should open a fancybox window with the content I pass it,

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('#test').live('click', function(){
    $.fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',  
            'transitionOut'     : 'elastic'  
            'type'              : 'inline',  
            'content'           : '<div>Test</div>',  
            'autoDimensions'    : false,  
            'width'             : 400,  
            'height'            : 400
            });  
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
  background: #000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

But when I launch that it gives me `undefined`, at first I thought it was referencing the wrong ID, but the HTML is sound.

I am guessing that it's probably something very simple that I am missing...

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Can you tell me what variable is undefined? Can you post your html code as well?

Comment: Not sure myself to be honest, all I am trying to do is launch a fancybox when the `#test` box is clicked, and have it display the content I give it, but for some reason every time I click the test box, I get `undefined` in the Javascript console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are missing the `,`
2. Remove the line `'type' : 'inline',`

You can take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/zkYTZ/

I am not sure why the `'type' : 'inline',` causes problem. Maybe it is a bug or Forces content don't need the `type` option.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a ","

```
$('#test').live('click', function(){
    $.fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',  
            'transitionOut'     : 'elastic' ,   <--------- 
            'type'              : 'inline',  
            'content'           : '<div>Test</div>',  
            'autoDimensions'    : false,  
            'width'             : 400,  
            'height'            : 400
            });  
})
```